# How do you make names the same in two different dataframes for Shiny app to work?

Tags: r, csv, append, shiny

I am writing my first Shiny application. The gist of the code is to read in a csv file, the user answers some inputs from the app, and those data are appended to the csv file. The intent is that this file is kept day-to-day and the app updates the contents. This file will then be used later for analysis.

My app does this successfully when opened the first time. However, when the session is closed and then reopened for later use (imagine closing the app before lunch and then reopening after lunch) the CSV file can no longer be appended due to "Error: names do not match previous names"

I first have an "empty" .csv with just a header row with three columns (A, B, C) called log.csv.

I then use the following code to create the Shiny App.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My 1st App"),

  #Enter Agent
  selectInput(inputId = "a", "A", c("Choose one" = "","A1", "A2", "A3"),
         multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),

  #Enter Concentration
  numericInput(inputId = "b", "Favorite Number", NULL, min = 0, max = NA),

  #Enter Detection
  radioButtons(inputId = "c", "Are you Happy Y/N", c("Y", "N")),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"),

  log <- read.table("V:\\My\\Path\\log.csv",sep=",",header=T)

)


server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- eventReactive(input$submit, {         
        t <- cbind(input$agent,input$conc, input$detect)
        names(t) <- c("A","B","C")
        t         
  })


     output$summary <- renderPrint({data() #outputs data in allotted field.

       write.table(rbind(log,data()), file="V:\\My\\Path\\log.csv", sep=",",
                             col.names= FALSE, row.names=F, append = T)
      }) 

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)'
```

The log.csv is the original blank file with the headers A, B, C.

The error obviously occurs because the names in the log dataframe do not match with the names from the reactive data().

In plain R, I can fix the issue with this code:

```
log <- data.frame(read.table("V:\\My\\Path\\log.csv",sep=",",header=T))
names(log)

a <- c("A1", "A3", "A2")
b <- c(0,1,2)
c <- c("y","n","n")
t <- data.frame(cbind(a,b, c))
names(t) <- c("A","B","C")
t
rbind(log,t)
```

So, I tried to use this logic and updated the reactive data statement in the server section (above code already reflects this update). It still doesn't work when the app is closed and reopened. I don't know what about having previous data filled in the log makes the names not match up.

I appreciate any help. I've struggled for days and have researched many posts. This is my first post so please forgive any etiquette that I didn't follow correctly. However, I'd be glad to be gently nudged on more appropriate ways to post or ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try with `observeEvent` if you don't need an output in your app. (I changed a bit the code to make it easier for me but the idea is the same).

```
library(shiny)
path <- "your path"
log <- read.csv(paste0(path,"log.csv"))

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My 1st App"),

  #Enter Agent
  selectInput(inputId = "a", "A", c("Choose one" = "","A1", "A2", "A3"),
          multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),

  #Enter Concentration
  numericInput(inputId = "b", "Favorite Number", NULL, min = 0, max = NA),

  #Enter Detection
  radioButtons(inputId = "c", "Are you Happy Y/N", c("Y", "N")),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    t <- data.frame(A= input$a, B = input$b, C= input$c)
    data <- rbind(log,t)
    write.csv(data, file=paste0(path,"log.csv"),row.names=F)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast response. This almost works. I will mess around some more to see if i can fix. Good news: It doesn't crash when opened again. Bad news: After opening additionaly times, when appending, it appends all the previous data again and again. For example, if on first instance there were 3 observations and the app is closed. On the next instance of the app, after 1 new use of the app, there are now 7 observations (the first 3, the first 3 repeated, and the new observation). I'll keep at it, but if you have a solution I'll take it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes!!!!! Thank you D!  This worked. Then to further answer my problem above, it was silly to rbind(log,t). The writing to the .csv with append was already binding it. Thanks again!

Comment: great to hear that! if the answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else who may follow I'm posting the final solution. This could not have been done without D. Alburez' reply. I modified his code just a bit to get the answer I was looking for.

```
library(shiny)
path <- "your path"
log <- read.csv(paste0(path,"log.csv"))

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My 1st App"),

  #Enter Agent
  selectInput(inputId = "a", "A", c("Choose one" = "","A1", "A2", "A3"),
          multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),

  #Enter Concentration
  numericInput(inputId = "b", "Favorite Number", NULL, min = 0, max = NA),

  #Enter Detection
  radioButtons(inputId = "c", "Are you Happy Y/N", c("Y", "N")),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    data <- data.frame(A= input$a, B = input$b, C= input$c)
    write.table(data, file=paste0(path,"log.csv"), sep=",",
                col.names= FALSE, row.names=F, append = T)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks again D! Now off to the next problem....